# How to clear 'segmentation fault (core dumped)' in while loop

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

`enter code here`This is just a portion of my code, but after using a debugging program I was able to narrow down that the segmentation fault is coming from accessing `i` in the while loop.

This is the input data:

```
30218294 Super Man 2.9
39324809 Spider Man 3.5
48201093 Papa Smurf 1.9
39482010 Mickey Mouse 3.2
49384832 Minnie Mouse 3.4
-1
```

I have tried setting `i = 0` prior to the loop and changing the conditions of the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student{
    char fname[100];
    char lname[100];
    int euid;
    float gpa;
};

/* Reads the data from a file and stores it in the array of structs */
void readData(struct student *db, int *size)
{
    const char* file_name = "input";

    FILE *infile;
    infile=fopen(file_name,"r");

    int i=0, euid;
    fscanf(infile,"%d",&euid);
    while(euid > 0){
        db[i].euid = euid; //**ERROR: Segmentation Fault**
        fscanf(infile,"%s%s%f%d",db[i].fname,db[i].lname,&db[i].gpa,&euid);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(infile);
    *size = i;
}

int main(void)
{

    int size;
    struct student* db[100];

    /* read info from file */
    readData(*db,&size);

    return 0;
}
```

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00400729 in readData (db=0xb7fe173d , size=0xbffff278) at func.c:17
17              db[i].euid = euid;

Comment: You didn't initialize `i`. `int i` does not set `i`'s value to zero.

Comment: and is there some space where db points to?

Comment: Yes it is a structure student                                                                                     struct student{
 char fname[100];
 char lname[100];
 int euid;
    float gpa;
};

Comment: My guess is that `db` is either not initialized, or is not large enough, or is null.

Comment: would I set euid to a value as well? if so, to what?

Comment: it should be set by the fscanf. Now you should better check that the fscanf worked by looking at its return value... For example your file could exist, and open correctly, but be empty

Comment: I bet it's an uninitialized pointer to `db`. But let's wait for the [example].

Comment: I updated my question, is that what you meant by minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

In this program

```
int main(void)
{

    int size;
    struct student* db[100];

    /* read info from file */
    readData(*db,&size);

    return 0;
}
```

`*db` is equivalent to `db[0]`, so uninitialized pointer value is passed to `readData`.

To read into an array statically alocated in `main`, the program should be like this:

```
int main(void)
{

    int size;
    /* allocate array of the struct, not array of "pointer to" the struct */
    struct student db[100];

    /* read info from file */
    /* remove "*" so that the pointer to the first element will be passed */
    readData(db,&size);

    return 0;
}
```

Adding checks whether `fopen` and `fscanf`s are successful will make your program even better.